# Angular 7 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at setTitle

Tags: angular

I have a cryptic error message on my angular Project 
`Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at setTitle`

The error message leads to this

content_script.js

```
function setTitle(result) {
    if(result[document.URL]) {
        document.title = result[document.URL];
    }
    else {
        var regex_list = result["regex"];
        for (i = 0; i < regex_list.length; i += 2) {
            if (document.URL.match(regex_list[i])) {
                document.title = regex_list[i+1];
            }
        }
    }
}

function onError(error) {
    console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
}

function init() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, setTitle);
}

init();
```

I did not create content_script.js, I guess this is something generated when building the project

The only place in my project where I use a setTitle is in app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Title } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: string = "MY TITLE";

  public constructor(private titleService: Title) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.titleService.setTitle(this.title);
  }
}
```

If I delete the ngOnInit content, the error still appears

EDIT:
setTitle leads to this chunk of code

title.d.ts

```
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be
 * found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license
 */
/**
 * Factory to create Title service.
 */
export declare function createTitle(): Title;
/**
 * A service that can be used to get and set the title of a current HTML document.
 *
 * Since an Angular application can't be bootstrapped on the entire HTML document (`<html>` tag)
 * it is not possible to bind to the `text` property of the `HTMLTitleElement` elements
 * (representing the `<title>` tag). Instead, this service can be used to set and get the current
 * title value.
 *
 * @publicApi
 */
export declare class Title {
    private _doc;
    constructor(_doc: any);
    /**
     * Get the title of the current HTML document.
     */
    getTitle(): string;
    /**
     * Set the title of the current HTML document.
     * @param newTitle
     */
    setTitle(newTitle: string): void;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your error is thrown from the `setTitle` method. Could you show `.ts` file with implementation of this method?

Comment: This is because `setTitle` is empty.Please check it and try again

Comment: How is setTitle empty ? this title is used as a parameter

Comment: I followed this for the setTitle function https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your array is empty:

```
var regex_list = result["regex"];
```

Try to add array checking before running loop statement:

```
var regex_list = result["regex"];
if (regex_list && regex_list.length) {
    for (i = 0; i < regex_list.length; i += 2) {
        if (document.URL.match(regex_list[i])) {
            document.title = regex_list[i+1];
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: I did not create that chunk of code and I don't understand where it's coming from

Comment: @ThomasFournet try to rerun your application by calling the following command `ng serve`

Comment: @ThomasFournet great!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, it resolved when I removed the Chrome Extension "Rename Tab Titles" from Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, my cache just needed to be cleared. The mistake doesn't happen anymore, sorry everyone